# Passing multiple parameters

Tags: function, variables, module, erlang

I'm trying to convert an existing C function to Erlang but am having a bit of trouble understanding how it's going to work. Let's say I have the following function in C:

```
    void(int *x,int *y,int z,int a)
    {
     if(z<a)
      {
     *x = z + a;
     *y = z - a;
      }
     }
```

How would I write something like that in Erlang as a function module? I understand that normally you write your function and it would return an operation. But what if I have to do calculations on multiple variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you may return a tuple like: {X, Y}

Here is a function that doubles two values given as input:

```
-module(my_module).
-export([doubleus/2]).

doubleus(X, Y) ->
    {X*2, Y*2}.
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(my_module).
{ok, my_module}
2> {A, B} = my_module:doubleus(3,4).
{6, 8}
```

Answer (score 2):

Operating with pointers - means that you may change state of some location in memory (for sequential flow it is not so bad).

But in concurrency environment this may indirectly cause unpredictable changes in every process, that pointed on that location (especially in race condition).

That's why there are so many concurrency oriented mechanisms in Java.

But this is not Erlang way. In general - there is no pointers, and no shared memory in Erlang.

You may store **state**, for example, in tuple `{ X, Y, Z, A }`, and pass it from function to function. Sometimes your functions will return **new** state tuple.

In the context of the above, your function may look like:

```
-module( my_module ).
-export( [ f/1 ] ).

f( { _X, _Y, Z, A } ) when Z < A -> { Z + A, Z - A, Z, A };
%% othervise - don't change the state
f( State ) -> State.
```